# css body background image clickable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to place an advertisement as a background image of my webpage. What's the best way to make the body background image a clickable link?

Comment: dup :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834579/how-can-i-make-a-background-clickable

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a background image clickable. Is your image taking the whole body space ?

Comment: The background image is shown on the left and right columns either side of the page content. This is the part that needs to be clickable

Answer (score 1):

Or you can you use javascript:

```
$("body").click(function(event){ 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    alert('oh hai');
});
```

Comment: @Riho, that is intented behaviour in this example. You can replace alert() function with anything you need.

Comment: I meant that it should show alert only when clickikng on background image , not in content

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make the body background-image clickable:

```
$('body').css({'background': 'url(yourimage.jpg) top center no-repeat'})
         $('body').click(function(e){
            if (e.target === this) {
                window.open('http://link.html', '_blank');
            }
});
```

You can also use window.location instead of window.open(). Hope this helps.