# set a background image to be clickable

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a background clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834579/how-can-i-make-a-background-clickable)

I want to have a clickable background image. but I am not able to do that. the problem is when i use

```
<div id="wrapper" class="bigshadow" style="background-color:  #fff url(/affiliate/uploads/images/image.gif) no-repeat right top"></div>
```

the image is not clickable.
when i use

```
<a style=float:right href="google.com"><img src="/affiliate/uploads/images/image.gif" /></a>
```

the image doesn't set as a back ground.
much appreciate for any help

Answer (score 2):

Set your `a` to `display: block`, height, width and background image.

Comment: don't forget to specify a with and a height in case the image is big